# is a good idea to use the view model as converter?

Tags: mvvm, converters, ivalueconverter

I have read this text:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/wpf-disciples/P-JwzRB_GE8

is it a good idea that the model has the responsability to convert the type of data? If the view model has not idea of the view, why to have properties in different formats to be used by the view?

If I use a converter at least I need to have my converter and code it, but the view model in this case knows nothing about the view, and I think that is better to use converters, but perhaps is a good option use the view model as converter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a good idea that the model has the responsability to convert the type of data?

No.  That's why that chain recommends using the ViewModel, not the Model, to convert the data formats.

> If the view model has not idea of the view, why to has properties in different formats to be used by the view?

That was the argument against this raised by Paul Stovell and Bill Kempf in that chain.  If you want to stay "pure" to MVVM, in general, it'd be better to build a converter, which keeps the logic completely within the presentation layer (View).

That being said, there's often a practicality issue/balance to consider here - if there's a scenario where you'll only be using this "conversion" a single time, it can be simpler to just expose the right type of data in the ViewModel, even though it's effectively adding a small amount of coupling, since it's far less code to write.  If the data conversion is something that can be reused, a converter is (in my opinion) more appropriate.